# What is the next-character perplexity of the PaLM model?

Tags: language-model

In the 2022 paper ["PaLM: Scaling Language Modeling with Pathways"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2204.02311.pdf), what is the bits-per-character perplexity of the resultant pre-trained model for next-word prediction?

Comment: Can you clarify why you're asking this question? What is "bits-per-character perplexity"? Why are you interested in it? I suppose it's not reported in the paper and you want to know if anyone knows its value for that model, i.e. "the resultant pre-trained PaLM model for next-word prediction"?

Comment: I'm asking what the log likelihood of a test character from the test set of PaLM is, averaged across sampled contextual windows the model can handle.